# How to get the energy bands of the Haldane model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-order

I am struggling with how to get the dispersion relationship of the Haldane model and plot it, just like this:

[image]

And then apply it to graphene nanoribbons (armchair) and plot it like this:

[image]

Here's a reference: [Haldane model](https://topocondmat.org/w4_haldane/haldane_model.html).

Answer (score 2):

The Haldane model hamiltonian for the full (infinite) 2D plane reads
$$
H(\mathbf k) 
= 
t_1 \sum_i\left[\sigma_x \cos(\mathbf a_i\cdot \mathbf k) - \sigma_y \sin(\mathbf a_i\cdot \mathbf k)\right]
+M\sigma_z
+2t_2\sum_i \sigma_z \sin(\mathbf b_i\cdot \mathbf k)
$$
in the crystal-momentum plane, with the notation explained in depth in [this link](https://topocondmat.org/w4_haldane/haldane_model.html), from which you presumably took your images. This means that the hamiltonian can be written in the form
$$
H(\mathbf k) = \mathbf B(\mathbf k) \cdot \boldsymbol\sigma,
$$
where $\boldsymbol \sigma = (\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)$ is the vector of the three Pauli matrices, which gets dotted with the vector-valued function
$$
\mathbf B(\mathbf k) 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
t_1 \sum_i \cos(\mathbf a_i\cdot \mathbf k) \\
t_1 \sum_i \sin(\mathbf a_i\cdot \mathbf k) \\
M + 2t_2\sum_i \sin(\mathbf b_i\cdot \mathbf k)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
to give the hamiltonian.

The nice thing about this expression is that *any* linear combination of Pauli matrices has simple eigenvalues, $\pm 1$, since it basically represents a Pauli matrix around the axis of quantization fixed by the direction of the vector that's dotted into $\boldsymbol \sigma$. If you care about the eigenvectors then you basically get them directly from the Bloch-sphere representation (though with some nontrivial handling of gauge issues), but if you only need the energy spectrum then that's not necessary: on a frame aligned with the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf n}(\mathbf k) = \mathbf B(\mathbf k)/B(\mathbf k)$, for $B(\mathbf k) = ||\mathbf B(\mathbf k)||,$ the hamiltonian reads
$$
H(\mathbf k) = B(\mathbf k) \sigma_{\hat{\mathbf n}(\mathbf k)},
$$
with the eigenvalues of $\sigma_{\hat{\mathbf n}(\mathbf k)}$ set to $\pm 1$, so the eigenvalues of $H(\mathbf k)$ then given by
$$
\pm B(\mathbf k ) = \pm \sqrt{
\left(t_1 \sum_i \cos(\mathbf a_i\cdot \mathbf k) \right)^2
+\left(t_1 \sum_i \sin(\mathbf a_i\cdot \mathbf k) \right)^2
+\left(M + 2t_2\sum_i \sin(\mathbf b_i\cdot \mathbf k)\right)^2
}.
$$

---

On the other hand, if you want to get the spectrum for a nanoribbon, then you need to do the Fourier transform (which gets you from the position representation to the crystal-momentum representation) in only one dimension, keeping the explicit matrix in the other direction and imposing the relevant boundary conditions. This then gets you a large-ish $n$-by-$n$ matrix $H(k)$, as a function of a one-dimensional crystal momentum and with $n$ the number of unit cells transversely across the nanoribbon.

And, unfortunately, there's no analytical way to get those eigenvalues ─ they need to be solved numerically for each $k$ you want to handle. This is generally quite efficient for smallish matrices (i.e. it's not a problem unless you want to churn $n$ up to the multiple hundreds or thousands), but there's no alternative to the numerics.